# using the $.post with php&jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Ok, Im trying to make a draggable CMS system, now Im stuck on the next problem.

When Im done dragging my 'div' I want to save my new left and top (x and y) variables in my MySQL database using PhP.

I get my left and top variables by the next line of codes:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#3" ).draggable({ 
        stop: function () {
            $.post("upload.php", {
                left: this.getBoundingClientRect().left,
                top: this.getBoundingClientRect().top
            })
        }, 
        containment: "#containment-wrapper", 
        scroll: false 
    });
```

my upload.php is:

```
<?
    mysql_query("UPDATE nvt SET left='". $_POST['left'] ."'")or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_query("UPDATE nvt SET top='". $_POST['top'] ."'")or die(mysql_error());
    header("Location: inlogged");
?>
```

When I'm done dragging my div there is just no reaction?

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/msqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Comment: [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) is going to **get you!!!**

Comment: haha just testing, mysql is easy and fast for me to write! just localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing *});* at the end. The code should be :

```
$(function() {
 $( "#3" ).draggable({ 
    stop: function ( event, ui ) {
        $.post("upload.php", {
            left: parseInt( ui.offset.left ),
            top: parseInt( ui.offset.top )
        })
    }, 
    containment: "#containment-wrapper", 
    scroll: false 
   });
}); //see the change
```